# Error consulta Oracle JPA Hibernate, omite parámetros

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, sql

Hola estoy intentando realizar esta consulta con JPA en una clase DAO

```
@Query(value="SELECT rca.area AS AREA, COUNT(rca.area) AS CONTEO "
            + "FROM ConteoAreas rca "
            + "INNER JOIN ConteoConsulta rcc ON rcc.grupoResolutor = rca.grupoResolutor AND rcc.fechaCreacion BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fechaDesde, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(:fechaHasta, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "
        + "GROUP BY rca.area ORDER BY rca.area ASC")
List<Map<String, Long>> findAllByArea(@Param("fechaDesde") String fechaDesde,@Param("fechaHasta")  String fechaHasta);
```

Las fechas que le estoy enviando son '09/7/207 06:00:00' y '14/7/2017 14:57:00' como String, al DAO llegan perfecto, pero cuando ejecuto la consulta, me muestra en consola que está ejecutando esto:

```
 select conteoarea0_.AREA as col_0_0_, count(conteoarea0_.AREA) as col_1_0_ from ROBOT_CONTEO_AREAS conteoarea0_ ROBOT_CONTEO_CONSULTA group by conteoarea0_.AREA order by conteoarea0_.AREA ASC
```

Como se puede observar está quitando el INNER JOIN Y EL BETWEEN, no es un problema de espacios, ya lo revise, y ya ejecuté la consulta en el gestor de BD y va bien, ahora si la defino como nativeQuery y ejecuto esta (osea no con las entidades sino con las tablas y campos reales)

```
 SELECT rca.AREA AS AREA,  COUNT(rca.AREA) AS CONTEO 
            FROM ROBOT_CONTEO_AREAS rca  
            INNER JOIN ROBOT_CONTEO_CONSULTA rcc ON rcc.GRUPO_RESOLUTOR = rca.GRUPO_RESOLUTOR
                AND  rcc.FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('09/7/207 06:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')  AND TO_DATE('14/7/2017 14:57:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
        GROUP BY rca.AREA ORDER BY rca.AREA ASC
```

la hace bien (creo porque no puedo ver el resultado pero la imprime bien), pero no puedo capturar el resultado en List> y se totea, alguna solución o alguien conoce el problema?

Nota: no creo que sean los ":" en la hora porque lo más curioso es que tengo otro DAO que recibe los mismos parámetros de fechas les dan el mismo formato y van perfecto (La diferencia está en el JOIN), pero no se cómo corregirlo o a qué se debe.

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo parece más SQL que JPQL; quizás lo que quieres hacer es una `NativeQuery`?

Comment: Por eso decia que si le agrego nativeQuery=true a mi @Query el parece hacerla (osea cuando veo como imprime la búsqueda es de forma correcta, pero si lo hago así no se como capturarlo, osea si lo cambio en vez de List<Map<String, Long>>, en que lo almacenaría?

Comment: Creo que estás usando Spring Data, que no es exactamente lo mismo que JPA (al menos, no conozco ninguna anotación `@Param` en JPA puro); estaría bien que actualizaras tu pregunta para reflejar este hecho. También deberías explicar que significa "no puedo capturar el resultado en List"; si hay un error o excepción deberías incluir el stacktrace.